# Enunciate CXF plugin for JAX-RS

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, cxf, jax-rs, enunciate

I am attempting to use the Enunciate plugin for CXF to generate documentation for my REST interfaces via the Maven plugin configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enunciate-cxf-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- check for the latest version -->
  <version>1.21</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>docs</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>

        <!-- the directory where to put the docs -->
        <docsDir>${project.build}/docs </docsDir>

      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I attempt to run the plugin I get an error from the command line with the command:

```
mvn clean install
```

The error is:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 'docs' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Marc

UPDATE:
I changed the plugin to this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>docs</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <docsDir>${project.build}/docs </docsDir>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-cxf-rt</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

It works but my JSON objects return types and parameters are not being documented.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
```

According to the [docs](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/executables.html), there may be some plugin dependencies you have to add.

I'm using the above `artifactId` in my Maven project with CXF to generate documentation using Enunciate without any problems.

Comment: Thanks.I actually solved this issue late last night using a similar approach you mentioned.  I just haven't had time to post an update.

Comment: re: your UPDATE regarding JSON objects. Enunciate doesn't seem to handle JSON objects very well. However, I was able to get it to document my JSON return types. See this thread on the mailing list for details: http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.enunciate.user/msg/668730.79293.qm@web50402.mail.re2.yahoo.com